# Advice for library with GeoSpatial Mapping that allows users to place moving objects on a 2D map

Tags: mapping, maps, geospatial, openscenegraph, cesiumjs

I'm looking for a library/framework/toolkit that will allow me to render a 2D map from real GeoSpatial data and draw objects on the 2D map.

Requirements:

- Map Tiling (when I zoom into the map, i want a more detailed image)
- Pan (ability to use the mouse to move around the map)
- Read various Geospatial images (satellite, street, etc)
- Ability to draw objects onto the map (based on lat/longs) and have them move. For example, I want to be able to put an image of a bird on the map and have it move and rotate correctly.
- Primitive shapes. It would be nice if it had built in ability to draw lines, circles, etc.
- Complex drawing. For example, I want to draw a compass and have it show the heading of the current heading of the bird.
- Mouse input. I want to be able to right click on the map and have a context menu appear. I want to click and hold an shape I draw on the map and drag it easily.

What I have looked at:

- OpenSceneGraph with osgEarth. It's great, and fulfills my reqs, but is really slow and I had to do a lot of weird things to get things to work (especially with dragging objects on the map).
- Cesium: looks promising, but somewhat slow, and I need it to work as a desktop application. I've seen online that some have managed to use Cesium inside Qt's Webkit, but I'm not sure I would want to take that risk.

EDIT:

- I really want to stay away from a web-based framework if possible.

http://imgur.com/52DaJtQ
Here is a primitive picture of what I'm want to achieve. The aircraft icon should move and the degree circle along with it. I want to be able to drag the green waypoints and have the lines redraw as I move a waypoint. The red sensor footprint should adjust to what the aircraft can see.
http://imgur.com/52DaJtQ

Comment: While there are certainly a few use cases that are currently slow in Cesium; nothing in your requirements list jumps out as one of them.  Can you be more specific about what you find slow?  We don't have built in drawing tools yet, but there are some community projects to create them; eventually we'll have official ones available out of the box.

Comment: @MatthewAmato I'm running the EarthKAMExplorer example in firefox and dragging/panning around the earth as well as zooming in and out is laggy for me.

http://cesiumjs.org/EarthKAMExplorer/

Comment: That demo is almost over 15 months old and was written in 48 hours as part of a hackathon.  Try some of the Sancastle demos:
http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html

Or check out this CZML demo.
http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/CesiumViewer/index.html?source=/Gallery/BAMS_C4ISR.czml&lookAt=Aircraft/GlobalHawk_1a

Also, because Cesium is using WebGL, it's recommended you make sure you have the latest video card drivers and browser version.  Finally, I would recommend downloading the Cesium distribution yourself and trying it out.

Comment: I see you want to stay away from the web; in that case nevermind.

Comment: @MatthewAmato ahh i see. yeah I'm trying to stay away a web based solution if possible. If it were web, it would have to work with the webkit internet browser so that I could use it inside a Qt desktop app. Thanks for your help and good luck with Cesium! It looks fantastic and when I tried it in Chrome is was much faster!

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps,  Open Street Map, Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenSceneGraph/osgEarth extensively and am not dissatisfied with its performance.

What kind of weird things did you need to do?

If you want, you can contact me privately to troubleshoot your situation. Me website is AlphaPixel.com and there's a contact form there.

Comment: First, see my edit: I added a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.
Second, I'll definitely contact you, thanks!

Comment: None of what you ask for seems out of reach for osgEarth. You can use it with a 2D terrain model, or with actual 3D terrain. You could even do a shadow-mapping sort of technique to simulate what can and can't be seen out the windows, if you have a 3d model. It will be less accurate with a 2d model.

I do lots of flight-sim and avionics stuff with osgEarth, and I think it's probably the best tool for what you need if you don't want a web framework. osgEarth does 2D map projections too.

Comment: Just sent you a message using the Contact form!

Subject: Request help from XenonofArcticus from StackOverflow user